# Resource mapping not working in spring 5 with no xml configuration

Tags: java, html, css, spring, spring-mvc

Resources are not getting loaded for following configuration.Please help.I am using Spring 5 with no xml configuration
Following is my resource handler function on configuration page

```
@Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
   }
```

and here is how i have referenced the resources in my jsp page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/util.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/main.css">
```

and here is where my resource folder is located
[resource location image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qWLk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way out.Everything was correct as described by me in the above question. The problem was with spring security configuration.u have to add code to bypass the security for loading the resource in the spring security config file`public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");`